# Oracle Export: ORA-31600: invalid input value EMIT_SCHEMA for parameter NAME in function SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM

Tags: oracle

Im trying to export a .dmp of an oracle database but am getting the follwoing error when I run the exp command

ORA-31600: invalid input value EMIT_SCHEMA for parameter NAME in function SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM

This is the first time I've tried to export from this server since it has been set up. Is there something I need to do to allow export to function in the correct manner.

THE FULL SOLUTION FOR ME WAS (WINDOWS MACHINE)

1) Open command prompt at C:\Oracle\Ora92\rdbms\admin

2) Logon to sqlplus as sysdba, to do this in command prompt you need to execute command
sqlplus  "sys as sysdba"

3) Run catexp.sql - this gets rid of some errors
(to run type @@catexp.sql in command prompt)

4) Run catproc.sql

5) Run catmeta.sql this requires to shutdown oracle, run the patch and restart as described below.

1)logon sqlpus sysdba
2)shutdown immediate;
3)startup migrate;
4)@@catpatch.sql;
5)Shutdown immediate;
6)Startup;

Comment: Wow. I'm kinda surprised you could do anything with that database :-) I have found that reading the readme.html file that comes with the patch to be a highly worthwhile exercise. In general, you need to patch the software and then patch the database objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Oracle are you using? Version 9.2 has the following issue if a patchset is not properly applied:

```
Symptom(s)
~~~~~~~~~~
You are performing a database export against your 9.2 database.  The database 
export abnormally ends with the following errors:

EXP-00056: ORACLE error 31600 encountered
ORA-31600: invalid input value EMIT_SCHEMA for parameter NAME in function 
SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 105
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA_INT", line 3926
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA_INT", line 4050
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 836
ORA-06512: at line 1
EXP-00000: Export terminated unsuccessfully
```

This is detailed in Metalink document ID 257986.1.

Unless you're running RAC, the fix is to run /rdbms/admin/catpatch.sql. Likely cause is an incompletely applied patchset. You may need to be in restricted mode.

Comment: Yes that was it in addition I had to run catproc.sql and catmeta.sql